# How to separate binary and optical stellar pairs?

Tags: gravity, binary-star

I have list of stellar pairs from The Washington Double Star Catalog (WDS), i.e. I have next parameters:

- angular separations
- position angles
- stellar magnitudes of both components

Additionally I have GAIA DR2 parallaxes (and other parameters) from SIMBAD database. How to distinguish between binary and optical stellar pairs?

Answer (score 2):

If they are both in the Gaia DR2 catalogue, then a physical binary should have components with similar parallax and proper motion.